# How to use a custom image upload handler in TinyMCE Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, tinymce

I'm trying to use a custom image handler for TinyMCE Blazor Component within a razor page, without success. The reason I need to use a custom upload handler rather than just allowing TinyMCE to post the request is that I need to add a JWT to the request for authentication.

TinyMCE configuration is done via a dictionary of <string, object>

```cs
@code {
    private Dictionary<string, object> editorConf = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"plugins", "autolink media link image emoticons table paste"},
        {"toolbar", "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline | table | link image paste "},
        {"paste_data_images", "true"},
        {"width", "100%"},
        {"automatic_uploads", true },
        {"images_upload_url", "/UploadImage/"} // works fine if no JWT required
    };


/// other code

}
```

I cannot use a C# method for the handler because I do not know the parameter types, the only examples I've found are written in PHP (which I am not familiar with) and js and so the parameters are not typed.

I have tried following an approach similar to what is suggested here https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-blazor/issues/19 by creating a js script that invokes a C# method that would then add the JWT and do the required work before returning the file path of the image.

```js
export function upload_handler(blobInfo, success, failure, progress)
{
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyApp', "UploadHandler", "this is a test!")
        .then((data) => {
            success(data);
        });
};
```

```cs
private static IJSObjectReference? js_imagesupload;

private Dictionary<string, object> editorConf = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"plugins", "autolink media link image emoticons table paste"},
    {"toolbar", "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline | table | link image paste "},
    {"paste_data_images", "true"},
    {"width", "100%"},
    {"automatic_uploads", true },
    {"images_upload_handler", (async () => await js_imagesupload.InvokeVoidAsync("upload_handler", null))}
};

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        js_imagesupload = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/imagesupload.js"); // js script
    }
}

[JSInvokable]
public static Task<string> UploadHandler(string value)
{
    // add JWT to request and do image upload work here
}
```

The problem with this is I get an error complaining about JSON serialization.

> rit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Func`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Private.CoreLib...

I can see why this would happen, of course Tiny MCE cannot serialize the lambda expression. I'd really appreciate it if someone knows a way I can get around this issue. I'm kind of new to Blazor so it's entirely possible I'm missing something simple! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer to this is that you can use a javascript file to store the config and this in turn allows you to set the images_upload_handler to a javascript function. Thanks to the TinyMCE contributor jscasca! https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-blazor/issues/60

So I created a file called tinyMceConf.js and stored this in wwwroot/js/
The file contains the config (tinyMceConf) and also the upload handler which calls a C# method.

The SetDotNetHelper is called from the razor component so that js has a reference to the dotnet instance. See this helpful article for more information [Calling .NET Instance Methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor Directly from JavaScript](https://mattjameschampion.com/2022/02/08/calling-net-instance-methods-in-asp-net-core-blazor-directly-from-javascript/) I had to do this so because I needed my method to be an instance method rather than static.

tinyMceConf.js

```js
tinyMceConf = {
    height: 400,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styles | bold italic underline | table | link image paste | emoticons',
    plugins: 'autolink media link image emoticons table paste',
    paste_data_images: true,
    automatic_uploads: true,
    images_upload_handler: js_upload_handler
}

function SetDotNetHelper(dotNetHelper) {
    window.dotNetHelper = dotNetHelper;
}

function js_upload_handler(blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
    console.log(blobInfo.filename());
    window.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('UploadHandler', blobInfo.base64(), blobInfo.filename())
        .then((data) => {
            success(data);
        });
}
```

Then I added this line to index.html (within the head)

```
<script src="/js/tinyMceConf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then within my razor component I set JsConfSrc to tinyMceConf (in tinyMceConf.js).

```
<TinyMCE.Blazor.Editor Id="uuid"
    Inline=false
    CloudChannel="5"
    Disable=false
    ClassName="tinymce-wrapper"
    JsConfSrc="tinyMceConf"
    Field="() => loadedTicket.TechNotes" @bind-Value="@loadedTicket.TechNotes" />
```

Within my razor component I have a method using the JSInvokable attribute that allows my js to invoke it.

```
[JSInvokable]
public async Task<string> UploadHandler(string base64string, string filename)
{
    // Within my method I use the base 64 string and filename passed from js
    // to do what I need and return the url of the uploaded image
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I passed the token in the URL

```
@code {
private Dictionary<string, object> editorConf = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"plugins", "autolink media link image emoticons table paste"},
    {"toolbar", "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline | table | link image paste "},
    {"paste_data_images", "true"},
    {"width", "100%"},
    {"automatic_uploads", true },
    {"images_upload_url", "/UploadImage/?access_token=your token"} // JWT service corresponds to adding a URL to read access_ token
};


/// other code

}

//server

services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(config.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token =context.Request.Query["access_token"]; //here
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };         
                //other code
            });
```